# Beautiful soup: processing cell data using Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am using python 2.7 with beautifulsoup to read in a simple HTML table.
After reading in the table, I then try to access the returned data.
As far as I can see, a python list object is returned. But when I try to access the data using statements such as cell=row[0] I get an "IndexError: list index out of range" error.

````
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# read in HTML data
html = open("in.html").read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"lxml")
table = soup.find("table")

output_rows = []
for table_row in table.findAll('tr'):
    columns = table_row.findAll('td')
    output_row = []
    for column in columns:
        output_row.append(column.text)
    output_rows.append(output_row)

# process some cell data
for row in output_rows:
  name=row[0]
  print name 
# fails with list index out of range error```
````

Comment: Your `row` is empty so `row[0]` throws index error. By the way, any particular reason for using `python 2.7`?

Comment: why python 2.7?

Comment: Python 2.7 is included with the RHEL 7 distro I am using. I figured it would be more portable than Python 3 code.

Comment: What is the correct way to iterate through output_rows and read data into other variables for subsequent processing?

Answer (score 0):

I have come up with this code, to parse each cell of a row into a variable, where I can then process further. But it's not very elegant...ideas for a more elegant solution, suitable for newbies, are welcomed.

```
  for x in range(len(row)): 
    if x==0:
      name=row[x]
      print name
    if x==1:
      address=row[x]
      print address
```